# Showing every Fragment of a ICMPv6 Ping in Wireshark

Tags: wireshark

i am currently pinging another Computer with a Payload of 4000 Bytes, but Wireshark is only showing me 1 Packet per Ping, but because the Payload is higher than the Maximum Transfer Unit of Ethernet, it should be 3 Fragments, so how can I show all instead of only one? I know it's probably very easy to solve, but I have no Experience using Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it would seem that you are capturing the packets on the same machine as you are pinging from.  In this case, Wireshark receives the entire packet *before* it's fragmented by the NIC due to [LSO (Large send offload)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_offload_engine#Large_send_offload).  If you want to see the individual fragments, then you would either have to disable LSO (not recommended) or capture the packets by some other means such as using another host on the same network segment where Wireshark is running in promiscuous mode, or from a switch SPAN port, or from a TAP, or at the receiving host, although if you capture at the receiver, you'll very likely see the same large packet behavior for the reply packets as you did for the request packet and for the same reason.

For more information on capturing packets over Ethernet, you can refer to the [Wireshark Ethernet capture setup wiki page](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet).